# TypeScript does not allow me to access data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have victory chart's component (not mine) with function that passes data of type `DomainPropType` (it is their type).

```
<VictoryZoomContainer onZoomDomainChange={this.onDomainChange.bind(this)} />
```

It passes data to my function. How can I access `x` in typescript (without using type 'any' instead)?

[image]

Error on `x`:

```
Property 'x' does not exist on type 'DomainPropType'.
Property 'x' does not exist on type '[number, number]'.
```

I am pretty sure that property 'x' exists.

Is it even possible to access `x` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be aware that `typeof []` also returns `object`, that's why ts complains. You could firstly check if the `domain` is an array. If not - return the `x` field value.

```
if (Array.isArray(domain)) {
   return domain; // domain is an array - return it
}

return domain.x; // domain isn't an array, it's an object - return x field
```

Comment: Oh so there was my error. You are absolutely right. Thank you kindly.